# Every customer, one item, multiple orders

Tags: sql-server

My question is actually healthcare related, but I'm going to provide a couple of mock customer,sales driven questions to make this question more practical for most users on this site.

Say I have one table with all the following columns:

```
CustomerID
CustomerName
OrderID
OrderDate
Region
ItemID
ItemName
SalespersonID
SalespersonName
```

Since everything is in the same table, I don't believe that any joins are necessary.

Question

1. Let's say that I run a store that pays its Sales people in the commission that requires customers make appointments. The commission is based on the number of times a customer has returned to that sales person.
   How can I find out which customers have only had appointments with the same sales person and have never seen a different sales person?
2. Alternatively, I can provide another approach to solving this problem.
   Is there a way to find out if there are customers that have only bought one item multiple times for separate orders?

For example, if Customer A, Jennifer Smith, really likes one specialty product, Extra Blue Caviar, and Jennifer buys Extra Blue Caviar every three months and has never bought another item in the store. Also, let's say Customer B, John Smith, buys Extra Fragrant Jasmine Rice every week and has never bought another item in the store.

How do I get a list of Jennifer Smith and John Smith along with Extra Blue Caviar and Extra Fragrant Jasmine Rice based on the criteria that they have only ever bought one item from the store multiple times?

Thank you so much!

Comment: There are several ways to solve this. You can use NOT EXISTS or COUNT. To provide a more detailed answer it requires more details about your data. This is a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ But this type of question has been asked and answered hundred and hundreds of times.

Answer (score 0):

For option #2

```
create table #t ( c_ID int,  c_Name varchar(20),  
o_ID int,  o_date datetime,  r int,  
i_ID int,  i_name varchar(20),  
s_ID int,  s_Name varchar(20))

;with cte as ( select
c_ID,
c_Name,
i_ID,
i_name,
count(distinct i_id) over (partition by c_ID) num_diffent_items,
count(*) over (partition by c_ID, i_ID) number_of_purchases
from #t)

select distinct
c_ID,
c_Name,
i_ID,
i_name,
number_of_purchases
from cte where num_diffent_items = 1
```

Comment: StrayCatDBA, I already habe the table with the necessary columns: CustomerID, CustomerName, SalespersonID, and SalespersonName. I therefore do not need to create a table. Since I already have all the information in the one table, what would be the query?